# Error Array to string conversion for Yii::$app->user->id

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I use this **Yii::$app->user->id** in my project for getting the user id but after I delete the cache I have an error: Array to string conversion

echo Yii::$app->user->id['id'] is work but why change from Object to Array?

Without any change in the code.

/* Remove Cache In Toolbar Widget */

```
Yii::$app->cache->delete('toolbar_model_user-'.Yii::$app->user->id);
Yii::$app->cache->delete('toolbar_blogModel_blog-'.$this->blogId);
```

print_r (Yii::$app->user->id):

```
Array
(
    [id] = 152
    [email] = ad_ji_di@yahoo.com
)
```

Error:

```
Array to string conversion

    1. in /home/public_html/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php at line 245
    236237238239240241242243244245246247248249250251252253254

         * @return bool whether the user is logged in
         */
        public function login(IdentityInterface $identity, $duration = 0)
        {
            if ($this->beforeLogin($identity, false, $duration)) {
                $this->switchIdentity($identity, $duration);
                $id = $identity->getId();
                $ip = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getUserIP();
                if ($this->enableSession) {
                    $log = "User '$id' logged in from $ip with duration $duration.";
                } else {
                    $log = "User '$id' logged in from $ip. Session not enabled.";
                }
                Yii::info($log, __METHOD__);
                $this->afterLogin($identity, false, $duration);
            }

            return !$this->getIsGuest();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: add code , please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem for PHP version.

update to PHP 5.6 fix this problem.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1029

Comment: Problem exists PHP 7.2

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->id
```

Comment: why? i use Yii::$app->user->id without any errors but now i have error? why change to array? i need fix this.